# Bluemix DevOps deployment error with launch configuration

Tags: manifest, ibm-cloud

I am trying to deploy the people in the news sample application and this is the error, **Could not find launch configuration manifest nor the top-level project manifest**. **Please restore it or provide a project manifest.**
I am following this one http://peopleinnews.mybluemix.net/deployinfo.html
When I get to number 8 the path has a ' . ' (period) on my UI and I can not remove it to type peopleInNews/

peopleinthenews/manifest.yml (below)

```
applications:
- services:
- ttn-cloudantNoSQLDB
- re-service
disk_quota: 1024M
host: peopleinnews
name: People In News
command: node app.js
path: . 
domain: mybluemix.net
instances: 1
memory: 512M
```

then I tried changing path manually (below)

```
applications:
- services:
- ttn-cloudantNoSQLDB
- re-service
disk_quota: 1024M
host: peopleinnews
name: People In News
command: node app.js
path: peopleinnews/
domain: mybluemix.net
instances: 1
memory: 512M
```

Can anyone tell me more of what this error with the project manifest is?

Answer (score 3):

The manifest.yml file is formatted incorrectly.  For the values you've provided, this is how it should be formatted

```
applications:
- name: People In News
  disk_quota: 1024M
  host: peopleinnews
  command: node app.js
  path: peopleinnews/
  domain: mybluemix.net
  instances: 1
  memory: 512M
  services:
  - ttn-cloudantNoSQLDB
  - re-service
```

Specifically, `services` is property at the same level as the other properties, and the service names should be properties nested under the `services` property.

YAML can be a confusing syntax to author; when in doubt, use the awesome CF Manifest Generator at http://cfmanigen.mybluemix.net/ to build your manifest online.

Answer (score 0):

The deployment instruction for the 'People In The News' sample application has been updated in http://peopleinnews.mybluemix.net/deployinfo.html#DeployJazzHub.  The important change is in the 'Command' field within the launch configuration panel.  Once the correct location of the 'app.js' is specified, the deployment should then go smoothly.